# MySQL trying to create trigger to update inventory when a new purchase is made

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have three tables, purchases (purchase_id, quantity_purchased, purchase_date,purchase_time, payment_method) inventory (inventory_id, amount, item_id) and items (item_name, price, notes, item_id) I need to create a trigger to update the inventory (amount-quantity_purchased) every time a new purchase is made. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_update
AFTER INSERT ON purchases
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE inventory
SET amount = amount - NEW.quantity_purchased
WHERE purchase_id = NEW.purchase_id;
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  That final `on` clause is just totally unclear.  I would suggest that you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: updated to include table columns and updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a foreign key that would link your purchase table to your inventory?

Below is what I brainstormed, it should work if you can determine what product you sold when you insert into the product table.

```
Create trigger inventory_update on Dbo.purchases
after insert
as 
declare  @inserted int, @stock int, @pid int
select @Pid= pid from inserted
select @inserted = quantity_purchased from inserted
select @stock = quantity_purchased from dbo.inventory 
where @PID= inventory. inventory_id -- This line needs a way to find out what the purchase item is

if @inserted>@stock
begin
print('Not enough Stock')
rollback
end
Else if @inserted<@stock and @PID is not null
begin
update inventory
set amount= inventory.amount-@inserted
where @PID =inventory.item_ID     -- Once again the issue is figuring out what your purchase item is on this line.
print('A Sale has been made')
end
else
print('There is an error in the process')
```

Comment: ok thanks I'll give that a shot. I'm being told i need to create a function before i call the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `purchases` table has an `item_id`.  If so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_update AFTER INSERT ON purchases
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE inventory i
        SET i.amount = i.amount - NEW.quantity_purchased
        WHERE i.item_id = NEW.item_id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i'm getting a syntax error around UPDATE and have no idea why